# Service worker: check if server(api) is reachable

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I was following this tutorial( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/service-worker-how-to-create-custom-offline-page/ ) for creating a offline page using a service worker in my react app. This works as intended (when no internet connection) but I was curious how can I check if my API endpoint for status is online/reachable because in order to be accessed I need to use a VPN and I want to display the offline page when I'm not connected to the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigator.onLine`

eg.

```js
console.log(`Online = ${navigator.onLine}`);
```

Comment: Isn't this just for checking internet connection?

Comment: Yes, if you mean detect if your VPN is connected, there is no built in way.   But you could maybe first check if your online, if so then do a sort of ping to your server / back end.

Comment: Right now I'm sending a GET request to my /status API in order to check if it is reachable  but the loading time is too long this way. That's why I was trying to find a better solution.

Comment: @RobertGutu Unfortunately using a VPN is transparent to the browser.  Loading time for a simple `ping` GET request should be instant, are you using a `GET` request that's intrinsically complex.